# "Ignore"-URL for crossroad.js when using the A-tag with slick-binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, crossroadsjs

I'm using knockout.js and crossroad.js. (The later was configured by yeoman. I'm not sure I need it, but for now I don't know how to setup the project in another way.)

I have many a-tags with click-binding like this:

```
<a href='#' data-bind='click: select '>
```

Unfortunatelly, href='#' causes crossroars.js to change the location to home.
If I remove href='#' from a-tag, the cursor over the a-tag buttons change to edit-cursor, which is not nice.

Can I use any other "dummy" value href-attribute which is ignored by crossroads.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the cursor with CSS, you don't need an `href` at all.

```css
.clicky {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="clicky">Whatever</a>
```

Comment: That's even cooler than an arrow cursor and more explicitely saying "this is a button". Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, this worked only for the main container site, but the style was not applied to the dynamically loaded ko components. Which is strange because BS-styles are applied. However, this is another problem. I did it inline in the components at the moment and the cursor works.